# TypeScript and Custom React Hook Api Service

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create an API Service for fetching data in all my components. 
I'm stuck with Typescript (i'm not really good with it)

I've created a custom hook:

**useApiService.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const useApiService = (url: string) => {
  const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8009'
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async (): Promise<void> => {
      try {
        const res = await axios(`${baseUrl}${url}`)
        setResponse(res.data)
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error)
      }
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [url])
  return { response, error }
}

export default useApiService
```

and then use this hook in my components like so :

**Header.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Form, FormControl, Navbar, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'
import { Link } from '@reach/router'
import useApiService from '../services/useApiService'

interface NavigationData {
  title: string
  ID: string
  post_excerpt: string
}

interface SiteData {
  name: string
}

const Header: React.FC = () => {
  const menuQuery: Array<NavigationData> = useApiService('/wp-json/wp-utils/menus')
  const siteNameQuery: SiteData = useApiService('/wp-json')

  const data = menuQuery.response
  const siteName = siteNameQuery.response

  if (data && siteName)
    return (
      <Navbar bg="primary" expand="lg" className="navbar-dark mb-4">
        <Link to={'/'}>
          <Navbar.Brand>{siteName.name}</Navbar.Brand>
        </Link>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            {data.map((item: NavigationData) => (
              <NavItem key={item.ID}>
                <Link className="nav-link" to={item.post_excerpt}>
                  {item.title}
                </Link>
              </NavItem>
            ))}
          </Nav>
          <Form className={'my-2 my-lg-0'} inline>
            <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Recherche" className="mr-sm-2" />
            <Button variant="light" className="my-2 my-sm-0">
              Search
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    )
  else return null
}

export default Header
```

But I have typescript errors `Type '{ response: null; error: null; }' is missing the following properties from type 'NavigationData[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.`

I would like to inject the data interface or type from my component to my custom hook but I don't know if it's the good way to do this, and how to do this right.

Thanks for your advices

Comment: `useApiService ` return `{ response, error }` but you assign it to `const menuQuery: Array<NavigationData>`. That why you got error. 
Do you want the `response ` in `useApiService ` have type `Array<NavigationData>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you initialize the state like this

```js
// TS will infer type for value of response as null
const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null) 
// TS will infer type for value of error as null
const [error, setError] = React.useState(null)
```

and return `{ response, error }` from the custom hook `useApiService`, TS will infer the return type as `{response: null; error: null}`.

If you want to create `useApiService` as a more reusable hook consider making it a generic, which will take a type argument T and return type will be `{ response: T | null; error: Error | null }`. For example,

```js
function useApiService<T>(url: string): { response: T | null; error: Error | null } {
  const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8009';
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState<T | null>(null);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState<Error | null>(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async (): Promise<void> => {
      try {
        const res = await axios(`${baseUrl}${url}`);
        setResponse(res.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [url]);
  return { response, error };
}
```

When you use the custom hook `useApiService`, now you just need to pass what response type you want as a type argument.

```js
interface NavigationData {
  title: string
  ID: string
  post_excerpt: string
}

interface SiteData {
  name: string
}

const menuQuery = useApiService<NavigationData[]>('/wp-json/wp-utils/menus')
// Keep in mind that the return type of menuQuery is 
// { response: NavigationData[] | null; error: Error | null}

// you can destructure the response and error from the returned value 
// const { response, error } = useApiService<NavigationData[]>('/wp-json/wp-utils/menus');


// same applies to siteNameQuery you can either destructure the response and error
// or use siteNameQuery.response and siteNameQuery.error
const siteNameQuery = useApiService<SiteData>('/wp-json')
```

P.S.- You need to create the interfaces for the response types which matches the response from your API, otherwise you will loose type information.

Comment: Thank you ! It's more clear in my head now ! I tried to use the generic <T> but I think it's only compatible with the function keyword ?

Comment: It is compatible with arrow functions. For example `const useApiService = <T>( url: string ): { response: T | null; error: Error | null } => { // code }` works just fine as long as you are using `.ts` extension for your file. When using `.tsx` extension things will error out `JSX element 'T' has no corresponding closing tag` because of syntax ambiguities.

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot for all

Comment: I like the generic version. But where do you set the options (like method type and headers etc)? Wouldn't you want the user of the hook to determine that? I don't see any method here.

Comment: @MattoMK there are a lot of things hard-coded in the PO's example because it satisfies the requirements for his or her's usecase. To create a more reusable hook, one would probably pass a second argument `options` which will contain headers, methods etc. Or pass only one object as argument containing all the required fields like `baseUrl`, `pathname`, `headers`, `method` etc.